# Connecting to Facebook with UWP Apps

Tags: c#, facebook, uwp

I am trying to get an authentication by Facebook on a UWP project.

This method keeps failing:

```
FacebookService.Instance.Initialize(FacebookClientID.Text, FacebookPermissions.Email);
var log = await FacebookService.Instance.LoginAsync();
if (log)
{
    return;
}
```

This method fails with "User cancelled the dialog flow":

```
FBSession session = FBSession.ActiveSession;
session.WinAppId = SID;
session.FBAppId = APPid;
List<string> permissionList = new List<string>();
permissionList.Add("public_profile");
permissionList.Add("email");
FBPermissions permissions = new FBPermissions(permissionList);
var result = await session.LoginAsync(permissions);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For creating and configuring  **FaceBook** app that used to UWP client app, you need to refer [**Facebook Service**](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/communitytoolkit/services/facebook) official document.

> The Windows Store SID is a unique value per application generated, and it not tied to the actual store publication. Creating a local application will give you a valid SID that you can use for debugging against Facebook.

Please use the following code get store id.

```
var id = Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Services.Facebook.FacebookService.Instance.WindowsStoreId;
```

**Remark**: From left side menu choose +**Add Product** Click to add *Facebook Login*. Ensure you set the following options in the UI:

[image]

```
FacebookService.Instance.Initialize("appid");
if (!await FacebookService.Instance.LoginAsync())
{
    return;
}
```

**Update**

Problem solved. Apperantly microsoft toolkit based on an old nugget which had to update manually.

Comment: I have got working answer from you earlier so I hope this will work too, OP is taking ClientID from the input which looks like user are filing the client id and secret (which is not required (login doesn't need app approval) and practical).

Comment: @Adrian, I have tested the above steps, it works, so i think op has not configure currently.

Comment: Problem solved. Apperantly microsoft toolkit based on an old nugget which i had to update manually. THNX

Comment: hi @odedbartov  May I add the comment to the case update?